# Trying to append_fields() to an ndarray, no error but nothing happening

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to append a new column to an array, no errors but nothing happening ... can some kind soul please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib import recfunctions
from numpy.lib.recfunctions import append_fields

#the_array = np.genfromtxt(file.csv, ...) dimensions 170 rows, 25 columns

jrows = np.ma.size(the_array)
the_field = np.zeros(jrows)
the_field[:] = 391
append_fields(the_array, 'minute', data = the_field)

#no errors, but nothing appended.
```

Comment: Is `the_array` really 2d with 25 columns, or is a structured array with 25 named fields?  Check `shape` and `dtype`.  It might also help if you showed the whole `genfromtxt` command (esp. the `dtype` and `names` parameters).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost nothing in NumPy will change the structure of an existing array in-place. `append_fields` returns a *new* array, which you ignore and discard. This really should be mentioned in the docs, but the docs currently list no return value, making it look like it's supposed to be a mutative function.

Anyway, don't ignore the return value:

```
new_array = append_fields(the_array, 'minute', data=the_field)
```

Comment: Wow thanks, that's the fastest I've ever gotten an issue resolved on SO. I thought it might have something to do with the array being from genfromtxt() ... I noticed that the_array.shape = (170,) and np.ma.size(the_array, 1) throws "IndexError: tuple index out of range" ... does that make sense?

Comment: @dts: That looks normal for a structured array.